# Is there a mechanism that enables to define the null elements for operators (0 for addition, 1 for multiplication, etc)

Tags: python, class, sum

This is really a general question in Python, that rose with the following code:

```py
class Toto():
    def __init__(self, val, n=""):
        self.val = val
        self.n = n
    def __repr__(self): return f"Toto({self.val}, {self.n})"
    def __add__(self, other):
        # Toto-casting
        if not isinstance(other, Toto):
            other = Toto(other, n="")
        return Toto(self.val+other.val, self.n+other.n)
    __radd__ = __add__

t = Toto(1, "1")
v = Toto(2, "11")
print(t+v)
print(sum([t, v]))
```

which prints as expected :

```
Toto(3, 111)
Toto(3, 111)
```

Now, for some reasons, I would like to remove the 2 `Toto-casting` lines in `__add__`, to ensure to raise an `AttributeError` when trying to add 2 objects that are not `Toto` instances - BUT I would also like that `sum([t, v])` works. For this, the only workaround is to explicitely specify the initial value as

```py
sum([t, v], Toto(0, "")) # outputs Toto(3, 111) as expected
```

Now what I was wondering is could it be possible to specify in the class the "null element for addition" in my class, that would be called by default as the initial value for sum ? Or in code, would this be acceptable (in a far-away python version for eg):

```py
class Toto():
    # this attribute would be called by sum as 
    # "sum([t, v])" become "sum([t, v], t.__null_addition__)"
    __null_addition__ = Toto(0)
    
    def __init__(self, val, n=""):
        self.val = val
        self.n = n
    def __repr__(self): return f"Toto({self.val}, {self.n})"
    def __add__(self, other):
        #if not isinstance(other, Toto):
        #    other = Toto(other, n="")
        return Toto(self.val+other.val, self.n+other.n)
    __radd__ = __add__
```

I guess my question in the end is : why this implementation for `sum` would not be acceptable in python ? Why can't we define an "null element", also called "identity element" for operators in python classe ?

More generaly, this could be expanded to other operators like `mul`: in python, why is there no notion of "identity element" for operators (as defined in mathematical groups). This notion could be used to overload the default initial value of `sum`for example (and maybe/probably more applications).

Hope its clear.

Comment: The default value of the second parameter of function `sum` is 0. It does not depend on the iterable and is provided at the time of the function call, before the interpretation of the iterable starts. In other words, the function chooses 0 as the start even before it knows that you plan to add Totos.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Do you want `t + v` to raise an error if one of them isn't `Toto` but `sum([t, v])` use default value for the one that is not `Toto`? If so, then no, I don't think there is a mechanism for that. Also, don't think `sum([t, v], Toto(0, ""))` is a workaround for that.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3315602/550094) for a bit of explanation about why the default start is 0.

Comment: You may want to distinguish between `t+0` (gives `t`) and `t+other_non_Toto` (raises an exception).

Comment: You could use the `PyMonad` library's monoids - this would mean that you would use `mconcat` rather than `sum`, but does allow you to define an identity element (what you call `__null_addition__`). See: https://jasondelaat.github.io/pymonad_docs/reference/pymonad.monoid.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid, https://pypi.org/project/PyMonad/

Comment: I understand my question is not very clear. I'll edit my post and rephrase it again here : I am wondering why there is no notion of "identity element" object for operators in python, as there are in mathematical groups (0 for addition operator, 1 for the multiplication operator and so on). This could be used to overload the default initial value of sum for example.